# C win32 app there can be compile and link but show nothing to me but process.why?

Tags: c, winapi, visual-studio-2013

there can be compile and link but show nothing to me but process.why?
 i have download another Similar mine but this show me the window. i am confused.

```
#include<windows.h>
#include<stdio.h>
LRESULT CALLBACK WinSunProc(//可以通过MSDN查看回调函数的声明方式
HWND hwnd,
UINT uMsg,
WPARAM wParam,
LPARAM lParam
);
int WINAPI WinMain(
HINSTANCE hInstance,
HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
LPSTR lpCmdLine,
int nCmdShow
){
WNDCLASS wndcls;//设计一个窗口类
wndcls.cbClsExtra = 0;
wndcls.cbWndExtra = 0;
wndcls.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)GetStockObject(BLACK_BRUSH);//黑色的刷子
wndcls.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_CROSS);
wndcls.hIcon = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_ERROR);//窗口上面是应用程序的图标
wndcls.hInstance = hInstance;
wndcls.lpfnWndProc = WinSunProc;/窗口过程函数。回调函数
wndcls.lpszClassName = "First MFC";//类名
wndcls.lpszMenuName = NULL; //没有菜单
wndcls.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;//CS：类的样式---水平重绘、垂直重绘
RegisterClass(&wndcls);//注册窗口
HWND hwnd;//创建窗口
hwnd = CreateWindow("MFC", "JLU", WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, 0, 0, 600, 400, NULL, NULL, hInstance, NULL);
ShowWindow(hwnd, SW_SHOWNORMAL);//显示窗口
UpdateWindow(hwnd);
MSG msg;//消息循环机制
while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0)){
    TranslateMessage(&msg);
    DispatchMessage(&msg);
}
return 0;
}
LRESULT CALLBACK WinSunProc(HWND hwnd,
UINT uMsg,
WPARAM wParam,
LPARAM lParam
)
{
HDC hDC;                              //Device Context的句柄
switch (uMsg)                       //针对不同消息处理过程
{
case WM_PAINT:                  //窗口重绘时，触发的消息
    PAINTSTRUCT ps;
    hDC = BeginPaint(hwnd, &ps);              //BeginPaint/EndPaint只能用在WM_PAINT消息中
    TextOut(hDC, 50, 50, "This is first MFC Program!", strlen("This is first MFC Program!"));
    EndPaint(hwnd, &ps);
    break;
    case WM_CHAR:                 //按下键盘字母键响应消息
    char cArry[20];
    memset(cArry, 0, 20);
    sprintf(cArry, "char is %d", wParam);
    MessageBox(hwnd, cArry, "WM_CHAR", MB_OKCANCEL);
    break;
    case WM_LBUTTONDOWN:
    MessageBox(hwnd, "LeftMouse Click", "WM_LBUTTONDOWN", MB_OKCANCEL);
    hDC = GetDC(hwnd);
    TextOut(hDC, 50, 100, "MFC Program!", strlen("MFC Program!"));
    ReleaseDC(hwnd, hDC);
    break;
    case WM_CLOSE:
    if (IDOK == MessageBox(hwnd, "是否真的要退出？", "提示", MB_OKCANCEL))
    {
        DestroyWindow(hwnd);                     //销毁窗口，同时发送WM_DESTROY消息
    }
    break;
    case WM_DESTROY:
    PostQuitMessage(0);                            //发送WM_QUIT消息
    break;
    default:
    return DefWindowProc(hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);            //对待不关心的消息，采用默认方式处理
}

return 0;
}
```

i post the WINMAIN and CALLBACK function i cant found any error. please hellp me fix this.

Comment: It's plain Win32 C app. You don't use MFC here. So please correct the title

Comment: Your WindowProc function is WinQinProc(), but you do register your window class with WinSunProc. That's your problem. There could be other problems too.

Comment: @AndrewKomiagin `WinQinProc()` should be named `WinSunProc()` but that's not the problem.

Comment: that a copy mistake.sorry theres no problem

Comment: Your indentation makes your code unreadable. You perform no error checking. Your problems are not what you think they are. You need to slow down and take more care in writing clear code, code that can be read, code that you understand, and performing proper error checking. You'll want to read documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all it is not an **MFC** application. It is just a very simple **Win32** application written in C.

As far as I can tell your `WindowProc` function is `WinQinProc()`, but for some reason you do register your window class with `WinSunProc`. That's your first problem. The other problem is the name of your **Window class (WNDCLASS)**. Please note that you should also **use the same Window Class name** registered in `CreateWindow()` call.

Here is the fixed version of your application (include `"tchar.h"` to make app **UNICODE** aware):

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WinSunProc(//可以通过MSDN查看回调函数的声明方式
    HWND hwnd,
    UINT uMsg,
    WPARAM wParam,
    LPARAM lParam);

int WINAPI WinMain(
    HINSTANCE hInstance,
    HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
    LPSTR lpCmdLine,
    int nCmdShow
    )
{
        WNDCLASS wndcls;//设计一个窗口类
        wndcls.cbClsExtra = 0;
        wndcls.cbWndExtra = 0;
        wndcls.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)GetStockObject(BLACK_BRUSH);//黑色的刷子
        wndcls.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_CROSS);
        wndcls.hIcon = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_ERROR);//窗口上面是应用程序的图标
        wndcls.hInstance = hInstance;
        wndcls.lpfnWndProc = WinSunProc;
        wndcls.lpszClassName = _T("MyClassName");//类名
        wndcls.lpszMenuName = NULL; //没有菜单
        wndcls.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;//CS：类的样式---水平重绘、垂直重绘
        RegisterClass(&wndcls);//注册窗口
        HWND hwnd;//创建窗口
        hwnd = CreateWindow(_T("MyClassName"), _T("JLU"), WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, 0, 0, 600, 400, NULL, NULL, hInstance, NULL);
        ShowWindow(hwnd, SW_SHOWNORMAL);//显示窗口
        UpdateWindow(hwnd);
        MSG msg;//消息循环机制
        while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
        {
            TranslateMessage(&msg);
            DispatchMessage(&msg);
        }
        return 0;
}
LRESULT CALLBACK WinSunProc(HWND hwnd,
    UINT uMsg,
    WPARAM wParam,
    LPARAM lParam
    )
{
    HDC hDC;                              //Device Context的句柄
    switch (uMsg)                       //针对不同消息处理过程
    {
    case WM_PAINT:                  //窗口重绘时，触发的消息
        PAINTSTRUCT ps;
        hDC = BeginPaint(hwnd, &ps);              //BeginPaint/EndPaint只能用在WM_PAINT消息中
        TextOut(hDC, 50, 50, _T("This is first Win32 Program!"), _tcslen(_T("This is first Win32 Program!")));
        EndPaint(hwnd, &ps);
        break;
    case WM_CHAR:                 //按下键盘字母键响应消息
        char cArry[20];
        memset(cArry, 0, 20);
        // sprintf(cArry, "char is %d", wParam);
        // MessageBox(hwnd, cArry, "WM_CHAR", MB_OKCANCEL);
        break;
    case WM_LBUTTONDOWN:
        //   MessageBox(hwnd, "LeftMouse Click", "WM_LBUTTONDOWN", MB_OKCANCEL);
        hDC = GetDC(hwnd);
        TextOut(hDC, 50, 100, _T("Win32 Program!"), _tcslen(_T("Win32 Program!")));
        ReleaseDC(hwnd, hDC);
        break;
    case WM_CLOSE:
        if (IDOK == MessageBox(hwnd, _T("是否真的要退出？"), _T("提示"), MB_OKCANCEL))
        {
            DestroyWindow(hwnd);                     //销毁窗口，同时发送WM_DESTROY消息
        }
        break;
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);                            //发送WM_QUIT消息
        break;
    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);            //对待不关心的消息，采用默认方式处理
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: That's your first problem as I mentioned. You should fix it first.

Comment: Please find the fixed version of your code and my comments what was wrong.

Comment: Make a diff and see what is changed/fixed. I told you that **wndcls.lpszClassName** and the *first paremeter* of **CreateWindow()** function should be the same.

Comment: I made it **UNICODE** compliant just to show you how to do that. That was not your original (root cause) problem.

Comment: thank you very much.i learn it first time.dont know it. thanks.again